# SQL left join exclude non matching records

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I'm working on this query (running on MySQL 5.6):

```
SELECT 
    veicoli_contratti.targa AS targa,
    veicoli_contratti.canone_noleggio AS canone,
    anag_convenzionati.nome AS convenzionato,
    SUM(noleggio_veicoli.fatt_prezzo_totale_noleggio) AS noleggi_incasso,
    noleggio_veicoli.modalita_noleggio,
    COUNT(DISTINCT noleggio_veicoli.id) AS noleggi    
FROM
    veicoli_contratti
        LEFT JOIN
    noleggio_veicoli ON veicoli_contratti.id = noleggio_veicoli.id_veicolo
        INNER JOIN
    anag_convenzionati ON veicoli_contratti.id_convenzionato = anag_convenzionati.id
WHERE
        (veicoli_contratti.data_cancellazione IS NULL)
        AND (veicoli_contratti.targa <> '')
        AND (noleggio_veicoli.data_cancellazione IS NULL)
        AND (anag_convenzionati.data_cancellazione IS NULL)
        AND (YEAR(noleggio_veicoli.rientro_data) = 2020)
        AND (MONTH(noleggio_veicoli.rientro_data) = 10)
        AND ((noleggio_veicoli.stato_noleggio = 'C')
              OR (noleggio_veicoli.stato_noleggio = 'F')
            )
        AND ((noleggio_veicoli.modalita_noleggio = 'S')
             OR (noleggio_veicoli.modalita_noleggio = 'OPO')
             OR (noleggio_veicoli.modalita_noleggio = 'M')
            )
        AND (veicoli_contratti.stato = 'OPERATIVA')
GROUP BY anag_convenzionati.id , veicoli_contratti.id , noleggio_veicoli.modalita_noleggio
ORDER BY convenzionato , noleggi DESC , canone DESC , noleggi_incasso DESC ;
```

I thought `LEFT JOIN` clause will produce a record even if there's not a matching record in table `noleggio_veicoli` but this doesn't happen.
The result include just records where a match is found between `veicoli_contratti` and `noleggio_veicoli`.
I tried also adding `OR noleggio_veicoli.id IS NULL` in `WHERE` clause but it's not the solution.
How can I fix this?
I created an SQL fiddle to try this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/269e68/3/0)

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I need to have the non matched records in `veicoli_contratti` to be reported with column `noleggi = 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understand is correct.  However, the `where` clause is "undoing" the `LEFT JOIN`.  Why?

You have conditions such as this:

```
   AND ((noleggio_veicoli.stato_noleggio = 'C') OR (noleggio_veicoli.stato_noleggio = 'F'))
```

Well, `NULL` fails those conditions so non-matches are filtered out.  This condition (along with other conditions) should be included in the `ON` clause.  For this one, it looks like:

```
   AND noleggio_veicoli.stato_noleggio IN ('C', 'F')
```